# How to assign picture to every topic on a Q&A WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to assign a picture which users upload for every question and which should be displayed along with every question. I'm using the 'media_handle_upload' WordPress function to make the upload.

```
<div id="submit-question" class="dwqa-submit-question">    
    <?php  
        global $dwqa_options, $dwqa_current_error;

        if( is_wp_error( $dwqa_current_error ) ) {
            $error_messages = $dwqa_current_error->get_error_messages();

            if( !empty($error_messages) ) {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-error">';
                foreach ($error_messages as $message) {
                    echo $message;
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="" name="dwqa-submit-question-form" id="dwqa-submit-question-form" method="post">
        <div class="question-advance">
            <div class="question-meta">
                <div class="select-category">
                    <label for="question-category"><?php _e('Question Category','dwqa') ?></label>
                    <?php  
                        wp_dropdown_categories( array( 
                            'name'          => 'question-category',
                            'id'            => 'question-category',
                            'taxonomy'      => 'dwqa-question_category',
                            'show_option_none' => __('Select question category','dwqa'),
                            'hide_empty'    => 0,
                            'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' ),
                            'selected'      => (isset( $_POST['question-category'] ) ? stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['question-category'])) : false)
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div>   
                <div class="input-tag">
                    <label for="question-tag"><?php _e('Question Tags','dwqa') ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="question-tag" id="question-tag" placeholder="<?php _e('tag 1, tag 2,...','dwqa') ?>" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['question-tag'] ) ? stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['question-tag'])) : ''; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-title">
            <label for="question-title"><?php _e('Your question','dwqa') ?> *</label>
            <input type="text" name="question-title" id="question-title" placeholder="<?php _e('How to...','dwqa') ?>" autocomplete="off" data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( '_dwqa_filter_nonce' ) ?>" value="<?php echo isset( $_POST['question-title'] ) ? stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['question-title'])) : ''; ?>" />
            <span class="dwqa-search-loading dwqa-hide"></span>
            <span class="dwqa-search-clear fa fa-times dwqa-hide"></span>
        </div>  

        <div class="question-advance">
            <div class="input-content">
                <label for="question-content"><?php _e('Question details','dwqa') ?></label>
                <?php 
                    dwqa_init_tinymce_editor( array( 
                            'content' => ( isset( $_POST['question-content'] ) ? stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['question-content'])) : '' ),
                            'id' => 'dwqa-question-content-editor', 
                            'textarea_name' => 'question-content',
                            'media_buttons' => true
                    ) ); 
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php if( isset($dwqa_options['enable-private-question']) && $dwqa_options['enable-private-question'] ) : ?>
            <div class="checkbox-private">
                <label for="private-message"><input type="checkbox" name="private-message" id="private-message" value="true"> <?php _e('Post this Question as Private.','dwqa') ?> <i class="fa fa-question-circle" title="<?php _e('Only you as Author and Admin can see the question', 'dwqa') ?>"></i></label>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="question-signin">
                <?php do_action( 'dwqa_submit_question_ui' ); ?>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
             var RecaptchaOptions = {
                theme : 'clean'
             };
             </script>
            <?php  
                global  $dwqa_general_settings;
                if( dwqa_is_captcha_enable_in_submit_question() ) {
                    $public_key = isset($dwqa_general_settings['captcha-google-public-key']) ?  $dwqa_general_settings['captcha-google-public-key'] : '';
                    echo '<div class="google-recaptcha">';
                    echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key);
                    echo '<br></div>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Ask Question','dwqa','Upload') ?>" class="dwqa-btn dwqa-btn-success btn-submit-question" name="submit_my_image_upload"/>
        </div>  
    </form>
```

My code starts below:

```
    <form id="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload"  multiple="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="55" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
    <input id="submit_my_image_upload" name="submit_my_image_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
          </form>
          <?php
if ( 
    isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['question-category'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
) {
    // The nonce was valid and the user has the capabilities, it is safe to continue.

    // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Let WordPress handle the upload.
    // Remember, 'my_image_upload' is the name of our file input in our form above.
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['question-category'] );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.
        echo 'Error uploading';
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

} else {
    // The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
}?>
</div>
```

This is the question-submitt-form.php of the plugin and I'm pretty sure I should implement the 'media_handle_upload' function inside the form so every uploaded picture will get the id of the question and with the press of submit the picture will be related with the question, but can't make it work. When it's out of the first "form" it's uploading pictures but they are not related with the questions.

PS: If there is another solution to accomplish this (Q&A Reddit, Stack Overflow style and image assign to every question I'm open for suggestions).

Answer (score 1):

I have some advancement in the task: Adding:

```
add_post_type_support('dwqa-question', array('thumbnail'));
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

in the functions.php alows me to asign featured image from the back end wich i show in front end with:

```
<div class="topic_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?></div>
```

Now the problem is how to assign featured image from the front end. I came up with the folowing code wich looks logical but doesn't work

```
<input type="file" name="imageFeatured" id="imageFeeatured"/>
<?php
            if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'post-thumbnails' ] ) )
    $thumbnail_field = esc_html( $_POST[ 'post-thumbnails' ] );
else
    $thumbnail_field = 'imageFeatured';
if ( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
    foreach ( $_FILES as $file => $array )
        $newupload = insert_attachment( $file, $pid, $thumbnail_field );
}

//attachment helper function   
function insert_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $set_thumb = false ) {
    if ( UPLOAD_ERR_OK !== $_FILES[ $file_handler ]['error'] )
        return false; 

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    //set post thumbnail (featured)
    if ( $attach_id && $set_thumb )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'thumbnail', $attach_id );

    return $attach_id;
}   
?>
```